# How to make sure there is no concurrent FragmentTransaction?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

In my app, I have a `ListFragment`:

```
Fragment fragment =  new MyFragment();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(resId, fragment, "tag");
transaction.addToBackStack("tag");
transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
transaction.commit();
```

When user taps <kbd>Refresh</kbd> button, it will refresh the list:

```
Fragment newFragment =  new MyFragment();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

Fragment oldFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
transaction.remove(oldFragment);
fragmentManager.popBackStack();

transaction.replace(resId, newFragment, "tag");
transaction.addToBackStack("tag");
transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
transaction.commit();
```

So it will remove the old fragment from stack and will add the new fragment into it.

The problem is if the user taps the <kbd>Refresh</kbd> button really fast, it may cause an overlay issue, which the old fragment is not removed from the fragment container.

I guess it is a concurrence issue.

If so, is there a way to "lock" the transaction, so that the other transaction will wait until the previous one is finished?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just refresh the list data instead of creating a brand new fragment? Creating a new fragment each time seems a bit wasteful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a new Fragment everytime user taps on Refesh button you can just create a refreshMethod in you MyFragment class and call that method from the Parent using the object of MyFragement as follows:

```
Fragment fragment =  new MyFragment();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(resId, fragment, "tag");
transaction.addToBackStack("tag");
transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
transaction.commit();
```

on Refresh button click:

```
fragment.refreshList();//Create this refresh List method in you MyFragment class
```

And inside your refreshList method you can notify the list

```
public void refreshList(){
//update the list as per your needs
}
```

Comment: Assuming there is a new list item added to the list. How is the refreshList() looks like? recall setAdapter?

Comment: If a new list item is added to your list then you can call the notifydataSetChanged method on the adapter to update the listview..